# Why does Jessep say that he and Markinson both went to the academy together?

Tags: a-few-good-men

In "A Few Good Men," why does Jessep say that he and Markinson went to the academy together?  The Marine Corps doesn't have an academy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The U.S. Naval Academy trains officers of the U.S. Marine Corps in addition to naval officers:

> As the undergraduate college of our country’s naval service, the Naval Academy prepares young men and women to become professional officers of competence, character, and compassion in the U.S. Navy **and Marine Corps.**

(From the [About USNA](https://www.usna.edu/About/index.php) page on the Naval Academy site.)